# i have creating a desktop application using Qt C++. Right click the QPush Button it opens the items like "BC,RT,MT. How to Write code for that

Tags: c++, qt

My problem was right-clicking the Qpushbutton it will show the items in it. how can we write this code using Qt C++? before I kept a combo box for the menu but now I need to keep the pushbutton Rightclick event to open the items?

""""""".h"""""""""

```
 class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
 {
     Q_OBJECT

 public:
     explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

   Bc *open;
 Rt *open1;
 Mt * open2;
 //QRightclickbutton *open3;



 //QRightClickButton(QWidget *parent = 0);

      ~MainWindow();

 //protected:

     //void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e);

 signals:
 void rightClicked();

 protected:
 // void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event);

 void pushbutton(QWidget *parent);


 void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e);

 private slots:
 //bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e);

  void on_pb1_clicked();

  void on_pb2_clicked();

  void on_pb3_clicked();

  void on_pb4_clicked();




 // void on_pushButton_clicked();

 // void on_pushButton_clicked(bool checked);



  void on_pb_rightclicked();



 private:
  Ui::MainWindow *ui;




 };




 #endif // MAINWINDOW_H`
```

""Mainwindow.cpp""

```
 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
     QMainWindow(parent),
     ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
 {
     ui->setupUi(this);
 this->setWindowTitle("Unical Project Title");   

    QMenu *menu = new QMenu(this);
   menu->addAction("BC");
    menu->addAction("RT");
   menu->addAction("MT");

   ui-> pb->setMenu(menu);

 //  connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(Rightclicked), this, SLOT(play()));
 //   ui->pushButton->viewport()-> installEventFilter(this);

  open = new Bc;
  open1= new Rt;
 open2= new Mt;

  QObject *w = new QObject;
 //   QString *select = new QString;
     ui->device0->addItem("Set as ");
     ui->device0->addItem("BC");
     ui->device0->addItem("RT");
     ui->device0->addItem("MT");

 //QObject::connect(ui->device0, SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(setText(QString)));

// open->show();

ui->device1->addItem("Set as");
ui->device1->addItem("BC");
ui->device1->addItem("RT");
ui->device1->addItem("MT");

ui->device2->addItem("Set as");
ui->device2->addItem("BC");
ui->device2->addItem("RT");
ui->device2->addItem("MT");


ui->device3->addItem("Set as");
ui->device3->addItem("BC");
ui->device3->addItem("RT");
ui->device3->addItem("MT");

   // int row= 7;
 //        int column= 2;

    for (int row =0; row<=ui->tablewidget->rowCount(); row++)
    {
   QCheckBox * cb = new QCheckBox(this);
    cb->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
    QWidget *w =new QWidget ();
    QHBoxLayout *hLayout =new QHBoxLayout();
    hLayout->addWidget(cb);
    hLayout->setMargin(0);
    hLayout->setAlignment(cb,Qt::AlignCenter);
    w->setLayout(hLayout);

       ui->tablewidget->setCellWidget(row,2,w);
 }

 }

   MainWindow::~MainWindow()
 {
delete UI;
 }

 void MainWindow::on_pb1_clicked()
 {
     ui->device0->currentText();

   if(ui->device0->currentText() == "BC")
    {
  QObject::connect(ui->device0, SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(setText(QString)));

     open->show();

  }
  if (ui->device0->currentText() == "RT")
  {
   QObject::connect(ui->device0, SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(setText(QString)));

  open1->show();
 }
 if (ui->device0->currentText() == "MT")
 {
   QObject::connect(ui->device0, SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(setText(QString)));

   open2->show();
  }

}

void MainWindow::on_pb2_clicked()
{

    ui->device1->currentText();
  if(ui->device1->currentText() == "BC")
   {
      QObject::connect(ui->device1, SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(setText(QString)));

    open->show();

  }
  if (ui->device1->currentText() == "RT")
  {
     QObject::connect(ui->device1, SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(setText(QString)));

   open1->show();
  }
  if (ui->device1->currentText() == "MT")
  {
     QObject::connect(ui->device1, SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(setText(QString)));

   open2->show();
  }
}
   void MainWindow::on_pb3_clicked()
{

    ui->device2->currentText();

  if(ui->device2->currentText() == "BC")
   {
      QObject::connect(ui->device2, SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(setText(QString)));

    open->show();

  }
  if (ui->device2->currentText() == "RT")
  {
     QObject::connect(ui->device2, SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(setText(QString)));

   open1->show();
  }
  if (ui->device2->currentText() == "MT")
  {
     QObject::connect(ui->device2, SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(setText(QString)));

   open2->show();
  }
 }

 void MainWindow::on_pb4_clicked()
{
    ui->device3->currentText();

  if(ui->device3->currentText() == "BC")
   {
     QObject::connect(ui->device3, SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(setText(QString)));
    open->show();
  }
  if (ui->device3->currentText() == "RT")
  {
     QObject::connect(ui->device0, SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(setText(QString)));
   open1->show();
  }
  if (ui->device3->currentText() == "MT")
  {
     QObject::connect(ui->device3, SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(setText(QString)));
   open2->show();
  }
    }


 //void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(bool checked)
 //{
 //    QMouseEvent *button= new QMouseEvent(this);

 //     ui->pushButton->button;
 //    connect(button, SIGNAL(rightClicked()), this, SLOT(()));

 //    qDebug()<<"right clicked";
 //}


    void pushbutton ::on_pb_rightclicked()
     {

       connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(rightClicked),this, SLOT (menuBar(show())));
     }

     //void pushbutton::on_pb_clicked()
     //{

     //}
```

what I want is while Rightclick the Qpushbutton it shows the items in it and please help me to do this. thank you

Comment: I have kept the combo box in my code to replace the Combobox into the Qpushbutton Right-click event. then it shows the items in it. explain how to add items in Qpushbutton and right-click event.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom context menu for the QPushButton.

First, you will need to assign the button context menu policy.  So when you initialize your MainWindow, you should also:

```
ui->pushButton->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
```

Then create a slot for when the custom context menu is requested (when the button is right-clicked):

```
//Your .h
private slots:
    void on_pushButton_customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &pos);

// Your .cpp
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &pos)
{
    QMenu contextMenu(tr("Context menu"), this);

    QAction action1("BC", this);
    connect(&action1, &QAction::triggered,
            []{qDebug() << "User selected BC";});
    contextMenu.addAction(&action1);

    QAction action2("RT", this);
    connect(&action2, &QAction::triggered,
            []{qDebug() << "User selected RT";});
    contextMenu.addAction(&action2);

    QAction action3("MT", this);
    connect(&action3, &QAction::triggered,
            []{qDebug() << "User selected MT";});
    contextMenu.addAction(&action3);

    contextMenu.exec(mapToGlobal(pos));
}
```

I'm not sure what you want to have done when the user selects an item from the context menu, so the above uses a lambda function when each action is triggered.  Alternately you could use a traditional signal/slot connection.

In the future, please try to include only the code for a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: hi Davek, what I want is to right-click the push button it will show the items in the pushbutton that are BC, MT & RT.

Comment: You want to show "BC", "MT", "RT" when the QPushButton (not a QComboBox) is right-clicked, right?  Can you elaborate further?  A QPushButton does not have a model with 'items' like a QComboBox does.  The sample above would show those three items in a pop-up context menu when you right-click on the QPushButton.

Comment: Actually When I have to right click the Qpushbutton it show the 3 options than i will select one of them it redirect to another window or Ui. 

I used the  combobox but my lead didn't accept that. he said replace the qcombobox with Qpushbutton r Qlabel.
while right click the Qpushbutton or Qlabel it shows the Bc,Mt and Rt then I'll select any one of them it redirect to that page.
 I don't know Qt it is my 1st project presently I'm learning the Qt. actually I tried this but it won't work please help me to do this.

Comment: If you want to use a QPushButton instead of QComboBox - use the above solution.  In place of the "qDebug() << "User selected BC";" this is where you should add your code to redirect to the appropriate page.

Comment: how to write the code for right-clicking the QpushButton